# plotting integer vs list using python

Tags: python, list, integer

I have made a list using a Python program that contains 5000 elements. I want to plot this list against a list of integers which looks like `[-2500:2500]`. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean plot? Be more specific. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 5):

Using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html):

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mylist = [math.sin(i/5000.*2*math.pi)+random.random()/10.0 for i in range(5000)]
x = range(-2500, 2500)
plt.plot(x, mylist)
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

There is a gallery of matplotlib examples (with source code) [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). It may help you evaluate if matplotlib meets your needs.

Comment: How do I save this plot in an image?

Comment: `plt.savefig('/path/to/image.png')`. See [savefig docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) for info on all the options.

Comment: it works, I want to save two images by a script. I am getting only one image when I do this successively.